# rails model / database

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm quite new to rails and am building a simple application.

1. Users can create a game
2. Users can join a game created by another user

Currently I have my models set up like this:
User - has many Games. 
Game - belongs to User.

Number 1. in my post works fine.

But how do I go about achieving number 2.?

Database currently looks like this:

```
create_table "games", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, as I'm unsure where to start.

Comment: Did you not read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)?

Comment: [Also this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new `model` called `JoinGame` which `belongs_to` 
`User` `model` should be like

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :join_games
 end`

`class JoinGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
 end`

By this you can achieve what you want and after that you wil have to create the logic